# Create a C# method to save all file paths in a txt file

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to create a void method in C# which will create a txt file and write all the paths of all the file names on a computer.

There is a cmd command, (`dir c:\ /s /b >c:\bla.txt`), but I don't want that.

How can I do it in C#?

Comment: Take a shot at writing it, and if you get stuck, post what you've done so far and we'll help out.

Comment: this requires knowledge in trees as far as I know,(if I am wrong then sry I am new to this). I don't really know how to start

Comment: @user535448 you'll notice there are several implementations below.  None of them require trees.  Using the .Net libraries makes it very straightforward.  Of course if this were an academic situation an instructor might require one to write it in a certain manner.  If I had to do this manually, I would likely build an array (or List<T>) of full paths to files in a couple of loops.  If you needed to represent the file system in memory for some reason, a tree or graph structure might be appropriate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Methods to look at:

- [`File.CreateText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.createtext.aspx) (returns a `StreamWriter` for the newly created file)
- [`TextWriter.WriteLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textwriter.writeline.aspx) (note that `StreamWriter` derives from `TextWriter`)
- [`Directory.EnumerateFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383571.aspx) (avoids reading *all* the files in a single call - instead, it will let you iterate over them using `foreach`)

Don't forget a `using` statement for the `StreamWriter`, so that the file handle will get closed even if an exception is thrown

Comment: I wasn't aware of Directory.EnumerateFiles.  I like that!

Comment: @Nate: I should have mentioned that it's new in .NET 4.

Comment: Yep, just realized that.  Changing my project type to 4.0 profile in Monodevelop now to see if it'll work in there.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
void GetFiles()
{
    StreamWriter wr = File.CreateText(Server.MapPath("") + "txt1.text");

    DriveInfo[] drive = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
    for (long count = 0; count < drive.LongLength; count++)
    {
        string[] dir = Directory.GetDirectories(drive.GetValue(count).ToString(), "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        for (long dr = 0; dr < dir.LongLength; dr++)
        {
            string[] file = Directory.GetFiles(dir.GetValue(dr).ToString(), "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            for (long fl = 0; fl < file.LongLength; fl++)
            {
                wr.WriteLine(file.GetValue(fl));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: wow `LongLength` on number of drives. I want to see this beast of a machine! :)

Answer (score 1):

Code is below. It is written on [Mono](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_%28software%29) on Mac OS X, so you'll need to change the directory. Also, if you don't have and run under administrator, it'll probably throw all kinds of errors in certain directories.

```
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        WritePaths("files.txt", "/", true);
    }

    public static void WritePaths(string fileName, string directory, bool recursive)
    {
        try
        {
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileName))
            {
                foreach(string file in files)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(file); 
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.Message);
        }           
    }
}
```

Based on other answers I've modified my method to use the newer `Directory.EnumerateFiles`.  I like this version much better.

```
    public static void WritePaths(string fileName, string directory)
    {
        try
        {
            using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileName))
            {
                foreach (string f in Directory.EnumerateFiles(directory, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(f);
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.Message);
        }           
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to write a recursive method although it cannot be a void method.
I would iterate through a given path say C:. or take out all drives using Drives System.IO class and pass to the method.
Then in the method I would iterate and rip out the filename in the directory and subdirectory.

Comment: I thought about a recursive method at first.  I realized 1) It wasn't necessary because .Net takes care of it for you with the Directory class. 2) Writing to the file while inside a method that recurses would be a pain.  3)  A deeply nested hierarchy could possibly cause an OutOfMemoryException when your stack gets too deep. 4) If something can be done easily without recursion, that's usually the best (cleanest, readable, obvious) choice.  Anymore, I can't remember what the code I wrote yesterday (well, maybe yesterday) does. :)

Answer (score 0):

> There is a cmd command, (`dir c:\ /s /b >c:\bla.txt`), but I don't want that.

You don't want to manually **type** the command and execute it in the Windows console, or you don't want to use the **DIR** command (you want to implement in C# yourself)?

If you just want a C# program that handles the manual typing for you, you can start a process using C# and run the built-in DIR command. See [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx).

```
Process.Start("cmd", @"/c dir c:\ /s /b >c:\bla.txt");
```

Simple, readable, and I'm 100% sure there are no bugs. So why not?

Comment: because I am creating it in a windows service, doesn't allow me to start a process like that